# Xdebug in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, lampp

I am trying to get Xdebug running with PhpStorm (Ubuntu). But It's not working at all.

I installed Xdebug:

[image]

This is what I added the php.ini:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

[image]

And I installed the Chrome Xdebug helper. But after restarting everything and setting PhpStorm to listen, I do not get any incoming connection from Xdebug.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I did. But I'm not getting any reaction.

Comment: Ignore external connections is unchecked. And There are no entries in Servers, but still nothing happening :/.

Comment: (removed comments, placed as answer with screenshots)

Comment: Collect xdebug log and show what it tries to do (where it tries to connect if it tries at all).

Comment: I do not get anything in my xdebug.log. I added xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log to my php.ini and have the same file in /tmp/.

Comment: That might mean that Xdebug does not see "debug me" flag in your request. Try with `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` .. or by placing `xdebug_break();` in your code (try debugging very simple script first instead of real project code) -- see if that will produce a log

Comment: I did and now I am getting: "Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded" when checking php -v

Comment: Maybe it's loaded more than once? Check `php -i` output -- what config files it loads and check them. No better/more concrete ideas from me (not a Linux user)

Comment: So I was able to fix one of the problems I had the xdebug settings in both of my php.ini files /apache2 and /cli. I removed it from my /cli and now it works in one of my projects. But in the others, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same running on Linux based, but atm on Windows machine, so I'll just copy that in, modify paths where needed:

#### `php.ini`

```
[XDEBUG]
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.6.0-7.2-vc15.dll
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200;
```

#### PhpStorm settings:

- `File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Debug` _> Turn off "Ignore external connections..."
- `File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Servers` _> Remove any entries here, refresh, during pop up with question to configure, make sure to enter map the project root, public folder, public/index.php file and vendor folders (not all necessary but better safe than sorry)

#### Server settings default

[image: Server settings]

#### Server settings with custom mappings

[image: Server settings with custom mappings]

#### Debug settings

[image: Debug settings]

Comment: Copied the ini settings and checked for the rest, but still nothing happening.

Comment: Have you turned off and on the xdebug phone icon in PhpStorm after these changes? (And/or restarted PhpStorm, Apache/nginx, etc?)

Comment: Yes, I restarted everything. But one thing isn't completely clear to me, should I remove all entries in File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Servers or add the two you have?

Comment: Remove all entries, then do a new request from your client/cli application. That should trigger an incoming connection to PhpStorm. That causes a pop-up. By default it will create the "default settings" in my answer, without mappings. If you're using a Docker environment (and possibly nginx), then you **may** need to add custom mappings like I put in my answer/screenshot.

Comment: Ok, so I was doing it right. But still do not get any changes. Thanks for your effort though.

Comment: Right, well, that's all of my settings that work out-of-the-box for me ;-) By the way, PHP 7.2.10 contains a bug with foreach loop array pointers, you'll want to upgrade 7.2.11 or higher. (see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75173 - fixed in http://php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.2.11)

Comment: I got it working in one of my projects. But it's not in the others. I think it has to do with the docker and absolute path on the server. What do you select for those? The path of the project (/var/www/nameofprojekt). And how do I configure the docker? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The shown pic with custom mappings is for project running on Docker. Each project would be unique, in it's own instance, or at least in our cases. As such, the `html` folder of `/var/www/html` **is** the project folder. It would depend on your setup what you need to enter. Next, "how to configure docker" is a new question out of the scope of this question.

Comment: After configuring the right php.ini and not having both of them modified with the xdebug settings. And creating a new project (something didn't work right with the old one's path when Incoming Connection Dialog was popping up) it works. So I will accept your answer as helpful. Thanks again for your help!